# Scatter plot in GEE with two series of data with different size

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am relatively new in GEE, and I am trying to plot what it should be a very simple scatter plot in another language such as R, but I am having a very hard time in GEE.

My goal is to display a scatter plot with two series with different size. Axes X and Y are representing Principal Components (PC) 1 and 2, respectively. The first serie represents values from flooded pixels and the second serie represents values from no flooded pixels. Therefore, I would like to display one serie: [PC1_Flooded,PC2_Flooded], and another serie: [PC1_NoFlooded,PC2_NoFlooded].

To distinguish flooded and no flooded pixels I selected a set of polygons on the GEE platform and set as FeatureCollection. Therefore, I have a geometry with several polygons for flooded, and another geometry with several polygons for no flooded.

The strategy I followed to get the scatter plot was to apply a mask with flooded geometry to PC1 and PC2 images, and a mask with no flooded geometry to PC1 and PC2 images. I used a mask since I did not want to distinguish among the different polygons in each geometry. The code I attach starts at the creation and application of the masks to the PC1 and PC2 images. Then, I merged PC1 and PC2 bands masked with flooded and no flooded geometries, resulting in an image with 4 bands: PC1_Flood, PC2_Flood, PC1_NoFlood and PC2_NoFlood, which contains all the data to represent the scatter plot.

```
//pcImage IS AN IMAGE WITH 4 PRINCIPAL COMPONENTS

//MASK CREATION FROM GEOMETRIES
var masked_flood = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(Flood.geometry()).mask()
var masked_noflood = ee.Image.constant(1).clip(No_Flood.geometry()).mask()

//APLICATION OF MASK TO PC IMAGE
var flood_masked_pc = pcImage.updateMask(masked_flood)
var noflood_masked_pc = pcImage.updateMask(masked_noflood)

//CREATE A NEW IMAGE WITH ONLY PC1 AND PC2 MASKED WITH FLOOD AND NO FLOOD GEOMETRIES
var pcImage_composite = flood_masked_pc.select(['pc1','pc2']).addBands(noflood_masked_pc.select(['pc1','pc2']))

//RENAME BANDS
pcImage_composite = pcImage_composite.rename(['pc1_Flood','pc2_Flood','pc1_NoFlood','pc2_NoFlood'])

//CONVERSION FROM IMAGE BANDS TO LIST OF VALUES
var pixelVals = pcImage_composite.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: sesia,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})

//ERROR BECAUSE THEY HAVE A DIFFERENT SIZE
var yValues = pixelVals.toArray(['pc2_Flood','pc2_NoFlood'])
```

At this point is where I do not know how to proceed. I thought that somehow I could display the scatter plot with these 4 bands. I also read that I could convert these bands to a list of values, and then plot them.

I seek any help to solve this 'simple' problem. I followed this strategy, but I am sure that I could follow others such as retrieving values from geometries without applying masks.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb928ca6124b5e1a9e9863c3763619ea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `ui.Chart.feature.groups` chart. Create a feature collection with properties for your x and y values, and a property to determine if the feature is flooded or not flooded.

```
var features = toFeatures(
  ee.List(pixelVals.get('pc1_Flood')),
  ee.List(pixelVals.get('pc2_Flood')),
  'Flood'
).merge(
  toFeatures(
    ee.List(pixelVals.get('pc1_NoFlood')),
    ee.List(pixelVals.get('pc2_NoFlood')),
    'No flood'
  )  
)

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: features, 
  xProperty: 'pc1', 
  yProperty: 'pc2', 
  seriesProperty: 'series'
}).setChartType('ScatterChart').setOptions({pointSize: 1})

print(features)
print(chart)

function toFeatures(pc1List, pc2List, series) {
  return ee.FeatureCollection(
    ee.List.sequence(0, pc1List.size().subtract(1)).map(function (i) {
      return ee.Feature(null, {
        pc1: pc1List.getNumber(i),
        pc2: pc2List.getNumber(i),
        series: series
      })
    })
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b5cf5f84aa740870062f89b90de6440

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!